# Twitter API: Self-login

Tags: c#, twitter

I am developing a project where I need to send tweets from my web applications. These tweets must be send via my account instead of user's account. The **OAuth** library forces us to show log-in screen which is not required in this case. I am looking for a way to log-in to twitter via my username and password (we are not asking user to submit username and password) and tweet a user activity or something...

the **OOB/Pincode** method is not feasible as well as it requires human interaction by entering pin code...

It could achieve if twitter have support for old authentication method (I believe Twitter no more support old auth method) .... Does anyone have idea how can I achieve this by **OAuth** or anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use Twitter [XAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) for this. It will allow you to generate a non-expiring access token for your application using a username/password. Once you have this you can dispose the username/password and use the token to authenticate further requests to the API.

If you want to send the tweets from the same account as the one your application is registered with, I believe you can also just use the access token provided in your app settings page. The documentation is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth). You can skip down to the part where you have the OAuth token and need to sign the request.

I've provided an example of how to authenticate against Twitter using oAuth and the application access token [here](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2011/08/twitter-oauth-authentication-using-net.html).

Comment: but it required explicit permission ... time delay :) I am writing an email.. lets see!